How to use Multiprocessing to loop through a x*y domain in python?
I'm trying to write some code that loops through a grid of x*y points and carries out calculations (see code sample)
Nx = 10
Ny = 10
for i in range(len(1,Nx-1))
    for j in range(len(1, Ny-1))
        temp = a*sigma[i,j]+b*sigma[i+1,j]+c*sigma[i,j+1]
        R = sigma[i,j]-temp

10 is used as an example, the actual domain size is significantly larger and takes a good while to loop through.
I tried to nest a multiprocessing loop within the loop, however I'm not sure how I'd get past needing to index the j+1 value:
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def mathstuff(a,b,c,sigma,j):
    temp = a*sigma[i,j]+b*sigma[i+1,j]+c*sigma[i,j+1] + c*sigma[i,j-1]
    R = sigma[i,j]-temp

Nx = 10
Ny = 10
for i in range(len(1,Nx-1))
    with Pool() as pool:
        j=np.arange(1,Ny-1,1)
        results = mathstuff(a,b,c,sigma,j),j)

This returns an error telling me a numpy array will not be indexable, which is fair, however I can't seem to figure out how to get around this.

len(1,Nx-1) cannot be right. This will generate an exception (TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (2 given)). You need to post code that compiles and can be executed, whether it produces the results you want or not. Also, See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Also, mathstuff(a,b,c,sigma,j),j) has unbalanced parenthesis (brackets).

Hello, Winston Zhang, your initiall loop through numpy could be replaced with numpy vectorized calculations. This would be the best option.

If you manage to express your computation loop-free, using numpys array broadcasting, it is usually faster than manually creating a process-pool. Numpy may or may not use thread-parallelism and simd-parallelism under the hood, it is up to the BLAS implementation which should be highly optimized.
Let's try it on your loop:
Nx = 10
Ny = 10
for i in range(len(1,Nx-1))
    for j in range(len(1, Ny-1))
        temp = a*sigma[i,j]+b*sigma[i+1,j]+c*sigma[i,j+1]
        R = sigma[i,j]-temp

This is sadly not runnable, but I think I understand the intent.
If sigma is a 2d-array of dimensions (Nx,Ny), a,b,c scalars, temp and R are (Nx-1,Ny-1)-2d-arrays, the computation can be expressed like this:
temp = a*sigma[:-1,:-1] + b*sigma[1:,:-1] + c*sigma[:-1,1:]
R = sigma[:-1,:-1] - temp

This should be way faster.

Below is the code with the solution on how to use multiprocessing. Here is some points that you need to pay attention in the code:

If sigma is a very large array consider to pass it as a shared data (Note that I'm talking about using array as a read-only). Otherwise you will create a copy of sigma array in each thread.
Arguments are passed to function in multiprocessing as a list/tuple, thus you will need to unpack them a,b,c,i,j = args in the function.
For multiprocessing implementation you still need to create all combinations of (i,j) and pass them as an arguments to the pool.
To apply multiprocessing to the function you need to map function to the pool with list of all arguments that you want to apply to your function: `pool.map(your_func, [(arg1,arg2,...),(arg1,arg2,...),...])


import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import product


# initialize shared memory for worker processes
def func_init_shared(data: np.ndarray):
    # declare global variable 
    # that will be shared across all workers in multiprocessing pool
    global shared_data

    # store our numpy array in the global variable
    shared_data = data


def mathstuff(args):
    a,b,c,i,j = args
    arr = shared_data
    temp = a*arr[i,j]+b*arr[i+1,j]+c*arr[i,j+1] + c*arr[i,j-1]
    R = arr[i,j]-temp
    return R


if __name__ == '__main__':
        
    Nx = 10
    Ny = 10
    a,b,c = -1, -2, -3

    np.random.seed(3)
    simga = np.random.rand(10,10)

    indexes = list(product(range(1,Nx-1), range(1,Ny-1)))

    with Pool(initializer=func_init_shared, initargs=(simga,)) as pool:
        # each task is a set of arguments to your function
        tasks = [(a,b,c,idx[0],idx[1]) for idx in indexes]

        results = pool.map(mathstuff, tasks)   
        print(results)


